# Function is called several times in vimscript

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I want to call a function when user presses `qq` in visual mode, so I wrote the following code:

```
function! FindSelectionMeaning()
  echo "FindSelectionMeaning"
endfunction

vnoremap <silent> qq :call FindSelectionMeaning()<CR>
```

The function is called but I have the following questions:

- Why does `FindSelectionMeaning` getting called once for each of the selected lines? I thought that it should be called only once
- Is there any way to call script-related function via `vnoremap` (in this case `s:FindSelectionMeaning` instead of `FindSelectionMeaning`)?

Comment: Ah, for the first question -- it seems that I need to place `range` keyword after `function! FindSelectionMeaning()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command was called several times (in fact the number of selected lines ), because, when you press `:` in visual mode, vim will automatically add range `'<,'>`, it leads to for each selected line execute the later inputted command. If your function want to be called only once, you can change your mapping like:

```
vnoremap <silent> qq :<c-u>call FindSelectionMeaning()<CR>
```

the `<c-u>` is gonna remove the range info after the `:`

In fact, you can get selected text in this way, I think it is easier, keep the `<c-u>` mapping, and change your function:

```
function! FindSelectionMeaning ()
  try
    let v_save = @v
    normal! gv"vy
    return @v
  finally
    let @v = v_save
  endtry
endfunction
```

This function returns selected text.

Comment: I found that it's possible to avoid this issue by adding `range` keyword after `function! FindSelectionMeaning()`

Comment: @FrozenHeart it can work too. it depends on what do you want to do in the function. If as your described in question, print sth, no matter what user has selected, only making sure that the function must be called in visual mode, you can just `<c-u>` using `range`, to handle the range in your function.

Comment: No, I need to get visually selected text in this function

Comment: Also what about the second question?

Comment: @FrozenHeart added my function to get selected text